# many to many in django

Tags: django, django-views

```
 class Employee(Profile):
   designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation)
   keys = models.ManyToManyField(Keys)
   parent = models.ManyToManyField(Parent, blank=True, null=True)
```

If i know some key id lets say key_id=12 how to query Employee for keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(not sure if I understood your question, but) this will give you the key assigned to Employee object `e` that has `key_id=12`.

```
# assuming e is an Employee
key = e.keys.get(key_id=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Isc` answer is correct, but it can be broadened. Basically, in a model instance containing `ManyToManyField`, that field becomes a [Manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/managers/) that can be used in a similar fashion to `Model.objects`, i.e. most of [QuerySet functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/) work as usual, as they have shortcuts [inside the Manager](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/db/models/manager.py#L116).

There are also limitations specifing to such "related" Managers, as they are called in Django terminology, but it's outside the scope of this question I think,.